# JavaScript parent object method invokes parent method rather than overridden child method

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a parent class having two methods, and creating a child class and overriding one parent method.
I have the javascript object structure as below.

```
function parent(){
}

parent.prototype = {
    method1:function(){
    this.method2();
    },

    method2:function(){
        console.log("I am in parent.method2()")
    }
}


//inheriting
function child(){
    parent.call(this);
}
child.prototype = new parent();
child.prototype.constructor= parent;

//overriding method2
child.prototype.method2 = function(){
        console.log("I am in child.method2()")
}


//creating child object
var childObj = new child();

childObj.method2() // will call the overriden method

childObj.method1() //here method1 will invoke method2 of parent.
```

How can I force to invoke overriden method always?

Or am I Trying something wrong?

Comment: its working fine, it is invoking `child.method1` and hence `child.method2`

Comment: "*here method1 will invoke method2 of parent*" -- I'm not seeing that behavior; in a [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/jfnnc/), I see "`I am in child.method2()`" both times. Or do you mean in your comment that that's the behavior you *want*?

Comment: I just pasted your code into JsFiddle and it is calling `child.method2` both times: http://jsfiddle.net/SUKHz/

Comment: btw you should set `child.prototype.constructor = child`, not `parent`.